# Git : How to get a snapshot of a git repository

Tags: git, archive, snapshot

I'm looking for the right way to get an archive of a git repository without the .git/ directory in order to send a daily snapshot to testers.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
git archive HEAD --format=zip > archive.zip
```

This does what it says on the tin.

More info here: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html

Comment: `git archive -o archive.zip HEAD` is shorter :)

Comment: Note that github does not support this protocol: https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-archive-a-repository/

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 14):

This will result in archive.tar.gz and add a prefix dir named "prefix-dir":

```
git archive --prefix=prefix-dir/ -o archive.tar HEAD
gzip archive.tar
```