# How to download git repository without using git

Tags: git, http, firewall

I am learning git by following some tutorials but i want a git repository for practicing the same.

But due to firewall or something , this command wouldn't work

```
$git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

Instead can i get the repo as a zipped file for download  or how do i recursively download as the [url](http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/) is displayed as html page with directories?

Comment: Refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615816/git-how-to-get-a-snapshot-of-a-git-repository

Comment: refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615816/git-how-to-get-a-snapshot-of-a-git-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O kernel.zip https://github.com/repo/repo/archive/branch.zip
unzip kernel.zip
```

Comment: There is still `wget` for Windows - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 0):

@PetrMensik has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785243/4421959) the question as asked, namely how to download a repository without using Git.

However, the OP mentioned that a possible reason for avoiding Git was because of a firewall. If that's the case then it's not the Git *program* you need to avoid but the [Git *protocol*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Simply replace `git://` with `https://` in the clone URL and it should work:

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

As the OP rightly guessed, the ports used by the Git protocol are blocked on many corporate firewalls. The same is true for the SSH, which is another protocol that can be used with Git. However, HTTPS traffic is rarely blocked, otherwise you wouldn't be able to access websites securely.