# How can I make a git submodule a normal folder?

Tags: git

I have a project that has a number of submodules and I am trying to make them act as normal folder and not repos. I have deleted the `.git/` folder in each of them,but they still act like submodules and when I run a `git status` they do not seem to show up as untracked files.

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: because I need a 'snapshot of the project'

Comment: Why is that in quotes? What do you actually *mean*? What are you doing with the snapshot?

Comment: it doesn't matter what I am doing. When I push the container application, I want the submodules to be pushes as directories. Now they are pushed as git submodules

Comment: Yes it does matter, because there could be a completely different way to achieve whatever it is you're doing and solving the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731) could make everyone's life easier. Pushing to what? Why does whatever it is care whether they're submodules or not?

Comment: I want to push the container app, with the submodules as simple folders, and not references to other git repos, as they are being pushed now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a submodule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Comment: But if you really just want a snapshot, you could use `git archive` as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/615816/1615903

Answer (score 5):

The submodule needs to be removed using `git rm` (this'll remove the submodule's files from your file system). You can then clone the submodule's repository into your repo (using `git clone`), remove the .git directory in the "submodule"'s directory, and `git add`!

Comment: There is a number of submodules that I use. Usually I clone the parent project, then I run a 'git submodule --init' so I get the submodules files. It also sets each submodule's HEAD in to a specific commit. So doing it your way, cloning each submodule seperately might not point them to the right commit

Comment: You can do a checkout of the correct version inside the directory before removing `.git`.

Comment: that is the problem if I do remove the .git folder it still doesn't show the submodule folder as an untracked file

Comment: Did you remove the submodule entirely, first, using `git rm`?